# How to prevent user from calling method based on condition with this parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to prevent users from calling a method based on a condition in the Typescript type system.

```
//condition 
type IsAllowed = false;

class Klass<Cond = IsAllowed> {
    create(this: Klass<true>){
        return {
            bar: "bar"
        }
    } 
}

const foo = new Klass;
//    ^foo has type Klass<false>

foo.create();//no error
//^type is Klass<false>.create(this:Klass<false>):{bar:string}
```

create method seems to be correctly inferred, the this parameter is not equal to the condition, but the compiler doesn't forbid to call it.

Comment: Are you doing this to provide hints on when a user shouldn't call that function or are you hoping for something that's "secure" and not trivially worked around?

Comment: There are two versions if the method and i want to point the user to the correct one based on his typescript config.

Comment: I haven't thought about doing this with generics, but since no one has jumped in: an option to consider that I would probably follow is to create a factory class that uses the config and returns the implementation you want under a common interface.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, remember that all must happen in the type domain.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got it. Typescript type system is structural and not nominal, even for classes.
In my initial example, every instance of Klass will have the same shape even when the name is different.
So the correct way (?) to do it is this :

```
//condition 
type IsAllowed = false;

class Klass<Cond = IsAllowed> {
    ignored:Cond;//parameter to change the shape of the class
    constructor(){
        this.ignored = false as Cond;//ugly hack, the actual value is ignored
    }
    create(this: Klass<true>){
        return {
            bar: "bar"
        }
    } 
}

const foo = new Klass;


foo.create();//error as intended
```